# Create a dataframe in R w/ lower triangle having the reversed values of mirroring upper triangle

Tags: r, dataframe

I'm a beginner in R and I came across a point in my task where I really need help after almost a week of trying on my own. I have a list of 100+ events and an another list of corresponding values to those events. I've learnt how to load, merge and sort these two lists.

1.) I need to create a dataframe/table where the first column and its description (event & value) are identical to the first row and I need to fill it, kind of multiplication table look alike, but instead of multiplication I need the absolute value of difference between the two values.

2.) This is a very laborious task to do manually, especially when events (and of course values) are being added as time goes by. So it's also necessary every time a new value is added to the list to update the dataframe & sort it in an ascending order along with its description (i.e. event)

3.) Now, the second step would be to divide/multiply every value of the whole square table (i.e. both triangles) by any number and store it as a new dataframe (and IF the result is not an integer, the resulting value = NA).

4.) The third step is to explore if the values of the two previous dataframes match with X (+-Y), where X = yet another list of numbers, constants etc., and Y is a deviation.

Any ideas?

The best I could do so far is to play around and manually adding column by column, f.e.:

df$ABC = abs((ABC - 1) - [DEF:PRQ])
df$DEF = abs((DEF - 1) - [GHI:PRQ])
...

I wanted to use real data to demonstrate my point, but it would be overwhelmingly confusing so I created a mock-up example in excel [mock-up example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2K0TH.png). I found it virtually impossible to do all this in excel which is a trash anyway... So as a result I got a square table consisting of two identical mirroring triangles - but I need only one AND I need the second one to contain the reverse of the original result as an absolute value, f.e. if the result of ABC - DEF = 306, I want the reversed value stored in the mirroring triangle = 603 instead of 306 since |ABC - DEF| = 306 = |DEF - ABC|.

Comment: Please provide an example of the input data frame, and, an example if the output data frame you need. Just enough rows to illustrate the problem. That will make it easier for others to understand the problem. Just enough rows to illustrate the problem is enough.